# Format method and rounding number

Tags: python

I don't understand how format & rounding numbers works, because for instance:

```
"{:.0f}".format(234.50) # returns 234
"{:.0f}".format(235.50) # returns 236
"{:.0f}".format(236.50) # returns 236
"{:.0f}".format(237.50) # returns 238
```

And so on...

Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python rounds to nearest integer, but if the decimal is 0.5 it rounds to nearest even integer. This method is called [round half to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) and is common in many programming languages.

This is confirmed in the documentation of the [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function as well.

> Return `number` rounded to `ndigits` precision after the decimal point. If `ndigits` is omitted or is `None`, it returns the nearest integer to its input.
>
> For the built-in types supporting `round()`, values are rounded to the closest multiple of 10 to the power minus `ndigits`; **if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice (so, for example, both round(0.5) and round(-0.5) are 0, and round(1.5) is 2)**. Any integer value is valid for `ndigits` (positive, zero, or negative). The return value is an integer if called with one argument, otherwise of the same type as number.
>
> For a general Python object number, `round(number, ndigits)` delegates to `number.__round__(ndigits)`.